# Pandas result of findall to single row

Tags: python, pandas, modin

hello I have csv file and I using pandas and my issue is when I using
pandas.Series.str.findall. What I wont is after call findall I would like to save value of result (what is array) to row in csv

this is my code

```
 data = pd.read_csv("input.csv")
 data["specificText"] = data["specificText"].str.findall(patternString)
data.to_csv("exportF.csv")
```

my input csv looks like

```
id, specificText

A1A, DEF_2122 bla bla DEF_87653 blla
A2A, DEF_7654 bla bla DEF_2199 blla
X1X, DEF_3542 bla bla DEF_0833 blla
```

and what I would like

```
id, specificText

A1A, DEF_2122
A1A, DEF_87653
A2A, DEF_7654
A2A, DEF_2199
X1X, DEF_3542
X1X, DEF_0833
....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close. Follow that with an `explode`:

```
data["specificText"] = data["specificText"].str.findall('([A-Z]+_\d+)')
data = data.explode('specificText')
```

Output:

```
    id specificText
0  A1A     DEF_2122
0  A1A    DEF_87653
1  A2A     DEF_7654
1  A2A     DEF_2199
2  X1X     DEF_3542
2  X1X     DEF_0833
```

Comment: thank you for your fast answer , you are awesome, its working